# 3d walkthrough with jpgs

Tags: 3d

I'm part time painter (artist), I need to create a 3D virtual gallery with my paintings on the walls so people can see them on internet. I'm looking for something "Wolf3D" style, but in my searches I've found only games and code about enemies, levels and all kinds of complexities that I don't need.

Is there a tool or JS library that can do that, a simple walkthrough only on virtual rooms?

I've read about **three.js** and **babylon.js** but require lots of programming, I just wonder if there are a simpler tool for such a specific task : **walkthrough "Wolf3D" style with jpgs on the walls**.